# How to annotate all points on a Q-Q plot when using `qqnorm`?

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to add names to the points on the graph?

I have two columns in my dataset (of 15 rows): the first consists of names, and the second consists of values. For example:

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(id = letters[1:15], x = rnorm(15))
```

Because I don't have many data, annotating every point won't produce a messy plot.

Comment: @李哲源 I think No, because there are 15 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reproducible example

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(15)
id <- letters[1:15]
loc <- qqnorm(x, ylim = extendrange(x, f = 0.05))
text(loc[[1]], loc[[2]], id, pos = 3)
```

[image]